# Format call doesn't indent as requested

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have this:

`(format *standard-output* "~v@a ~a ~%" (* 5 indent) "End of Parent" (* 5 indent))`

The curious issue is that `(* 5 indent)` is added as a debug item, and it is correct in the printout. However, the text is not indented when called inside my function, even though it prints out the correct `indent` value. If I just perform this line at the REPL, it prints out correctly, with indentation. My entire function is this:

```
(defun print-object-and-children-data (object indent)
  "Recursively prints a chart object and its children,
   with each child level indented further."
  (let ((children (get-chart-children object)))
    ;; This indents correctly.
    (format *standard-output* "~v@a Level: ~a~%"
            (* 5 indent) object indent)
    (mapc (lambda (x)
            (when x (print-object-and-children-data x (+ 1 indent))))
          children)
    ;; This does not.
    (format *standard-output* "~v@a ~a ~%"
            (* 5 indent) "End of Parent" (* 5 indent))))
```

All text content is correct. Also, whether that final `format` is part of the `let` makes no difference (it doesn't need anything from `children`). Something in this function is somehow affecting the indentation of the `format` call, but since the format prints out the correct indent value, what could be the cause of no indentation?

Comment: A recent question, [Lisp format a character a number of times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20072959/1281433) describes a number of ways to format a character (e.g,. `#\space`) a certain number of times.  If you're looking to print a certain number of spaces, you might use one of those approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `v` in `~v@A` does not specify indentation.  It specifies field width.  Try this:

```
(dolist (i '(5 10 15))
  (dolist (x '(1 123 12345))
    (format t ">~v@A< (i=~D)~%" i x i)))
```

Note how the output is not aligned to the left.

Here's one possible way to have indented output:

```
(dolist (i '(5 10 15))
  (dolist (x '(1 123 12345))
    (format t ">~vA~A< (i=~D)~%" i " " x i)))
```

(Fixing the bug here is left as an exercise.)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by removing the `@`, adding a `~a`, and adding an empty space in the format arguments, the space being used as the indenter. Like so `(format t "~va~a ..." (indent) " " ...)` Is there a way to affect text positioning without putting the text in the format arguments? Would be nice to inject whitespace without also having to move an arbitrary word out of the format text string and into the format tail arguments. Like putting an empty space in this example.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get indented output, you could also use `format`'s [tabulate (~t) directive](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cfa.htm):

```
(dolist (i '(0 5 10 15 20))
   (format t "~&~vt~a~%" i i))
```

The `@`modifier may be used if you want relative tabulation instead of absolute tabulation.