# Repeat string/character with (format)

Tags: common-lisp, string-formatting

Is there a repeat directive for `(format)` in Common lisp, something like(I know this won't work):

```
(format t "~5C" #\*)
```

Just wondering if there isn't a more elegant way to do it than this:(from [rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Repeat_a_string#Common_Lisp)
)

```
(defun repeat-string (n string)
  (with-output-to-string (stream)
    (loop repeat n do (write-string string stream))))

(princ (repeat-string 5 "hi"))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lisp format a character a number of times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072959/lisp-format-a-character-a-number-of-times)

Comment: I just voted to close as a duplicate based on your first example which was just trying to repeat a *character*.  You second example, though, repeats a whole string, and not all the answers in the possible duplicate address that situation.  I think I'm going to retract my close vote.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: that's why I wrote an answer. I think you are right.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
(defun write-repeated-string (n string stream)
  (loop repeat n do (write-string string stream)))

(write-repeated-string 5 "hi" *standard-output*))
```

Generally you can use the format iteration:

```
(format t "~v@{~A~:*~}" 5 "hi")
```

`~A` can output all kinds of items, not just characters. For more information see uselpa's linked answers.

Above takes the iteration number from the first argument. Thus the `v` behind the tilde.

The rest of the arguments will be consumed by the iteration. Thus the `@`.

Inside the iteration we go back one element. Thus `~:*`.

It's similar to `(format t "~v{~A~:*~}" 5 '("hi"))`, which might be simpler to understand.

Comment: (For anyone who might find the first a little cryptic, like I did): `~@{` takes the rest of the iteration's args as lists.

Comment: I found it interesting that in SBCL the loop version compiles to 25 lines of Assembly, while the format version compiles to 189 lines.

Comment: https://gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html