# Printing a list in outline form

Tags: format, common-lisp, pretty-print

Can the common-lisp pretty printer be easily configured to print out any deeply nested list in "outline" form, or is this a job for format? Eg, '(a (b c (d e (f)) g)) should come out looking something like the following, where each cdr element steps down a level from the car:

```
A
 B
 C
  D
  E
   F
 G
```

Comment: Do you care about parentheses? Using PPRINT withink a narrow column will usually do something very close to this.

Comment: Yes, setting *print-right-margin* to 2 works. Thanks. However, it would still be interesting to know how to do this with format--mainly, how to include a variable number of tabs in the control string, as in ~nI (indent n blocks).

Comment: for that, have a look at [Lisp format a character a number of times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072959/lisp-format-a-character-a-number-of-times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the ~nT format directive. This will print the next argument at the n-th column:

```
(format t "~30T~a" 'a)
                              A
```

If the column is variable, then use ~vt to use the first argument as the column value:

```
(format t "~VT~a" 10 'a)
          A
```

This will print 'A' at the 10-th column